# Google cloud storage - Split files by value in the file

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I need to read a file from Google Cloud storage and split it into multiple files based on transaction_date which is a field in the file. File is about 6 TB in size (broken in to multiple files). What's the most effective ways to achieve this? Do I have to use Dataflow or Dataproc, any other simple way to do this?

Comment: Approximately how many records do you expect to have per transaction_date? And what's the file format of your input format, and are you planning the same file format for the output? (Is it newline-separated CSV, or JSON, or something similar?)

Comment: 90% of data is for one date, remaining 10% spread over upto 10 days. newline-separated CSV, I am planning the same format in the output. Just need to put one file into upto 11 files (90% today + 10% for past 10 days).

Comment: Do you need all the records associated with a single transaction_date in a *single* file, or did you just want to organize it in such a way that you can easily get all the data for a transaction date, possibly by organizing into smaller files divided by a different directory per transaction date?

Answer (score 1):

I take it to mean that you want to write a separate (sharded) file per `transaction_date`. There isn't any direct support for this in the `TextIO.Write` that ships with Dataflow, but since it sounds like you have a special case where you know the date range, so you manually create ~11 different filtered `TextIO.Write` transforms.

```java
PCollection<Record> input = ...

for (Date transaction_date : known_transaction_dates) {
  input.apply(Filter.by(<record has this date>)
       .apply(TextIO.Write.to(
           String.format("gs://my-bucket/output/%s", transaction_date)));
}
```

This is certainly not ideal. For `BigQueryIO` there is a feature to write to a different table based on the windowing of the data - similar functionality added to `TextIO` might address your use case. Otherwise, data-dependent writes of various sorts are on our radar and include cases like yours.